# AWS Neptune/Gremlin: merge edge exists query and insert edge query into one query

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have the following query to check is an edge exists:

```
g.V("N001").hasLabel("my-type").out("parent").hasId("N002").hasLabel("my-type").limit(1).hasNext()
```

I also have the afterward query to insert the edge is not exists:

```
g.V("N001").hasLabel("my-type").as("a").V("N002").hasLabel("my-type").as("b").addE("parent").from("a").to("b")
```

My question is how can I merge this two query into one query?

Answer (score 0):

The commonly used recipe to achieve this in a single query is the `fold..coalesce..unfold` pattern. In the case of your query it will be something like:

```java
g.V("N001").hasLabel("my-type").
  out("parent").
  hasId("N002").hasLabel("my-type").
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(), addE('parent').from('N001').to('N002'))
```

Note ID values are unique and either will exist or not exist and given you know the ID you are looking for, the label check is not needed unless you are not sure if an ID you are using is of that type (label).

The query will either return the existing vertex, or the newly created edge. You can of course edit the query to return the existing edge, if preferred.

Comment: How do I add label ""my-type" back into the query? Because I have different labels in the system.

Comment: You can add it back in the way you had it, I will edit the answer, but if you use an explicit ID, the label check in many ways is redundant unless you are not sure if that ID is of the right type (label)

Comment: How do you add back the label type for "addE('parent').from('N001').to('N002')"..?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question . Which label are you referring to? The query already checked both labels before the `coalesce`